# How to replace a string with another string in a column in R?

Tags: r, csv, gsub

I have a csv file like

Data.csv

```
Id,Name,City
23,radu,Los Angeles
34,tree,Chicago
rtet,great,Miami
rtet,francis,Paris
```

where

```
  record <- read.csv("Data.csv",header=TRUE);
  Identity <- record$Id
```

I used

```
  gsub("rtet","67",Identity)
```

But it does not work.

How to replace "rtet" in the csv file with "67" in R? New to R.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `record$Id[which(record$Id=="rtet")] <- "67"`

Answer (score 2):

```
record$Id<-gsub("rtet","67",record$Id)
```

works for me...

Comment: But in my case it is not working, ok I will take a look at it myself.